# How to return one single string from matching dictionary values?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to return one string of selected values from a dictionary. When I iterate over the dictionary and the array I am fetching the keys from, I can print out the value, but as different strings, not combined.

So far I have iterated over the collection types, and tried map, filter, reduce to some extent. Also tried to put the results into arrays and dictionaries to use .joined, but I am getting nil all the time.

This is the dictionary I am getting the values from:

```
let letterDict = ["a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3", "d": "4"]
```

This is the array I am querying from:

```
let characterArray = ["a", "b"]
```

This is the code I was able to get the results from:

```
func convertText(_ input: String) -> String {
    var expectedText: String?

    for character in characterArray {
        for (key, value) in letterDict {
            if key.contains(character) {
                print(value)
                expectedText = value
            }
        }
    }
    return expectedText ?? input
}
```

I am trying to return `12`, but what I get is:

```
1
2
```

all the time. Even when I try to map them to an array, it just returns separate arrays (or dictionaries). And when I try to append to an array, it just returns nil.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually what you return from that function is 2. Not even
1
2
That result comes because you print the values. If you want to print the values in the same line use;

`print(char, terminator: "")`
You already have a correct answer for the real question given by @Dávid Pásztor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append `value` to `expectedText` rather than assign it.

```
func convertText(_ input: String) -> String {
    var expectedText = ""

    for character in characterArray {
        for (key, value) in letterDict {
            if key.contains(character) {
                expectedText += value
            }
        }
    }
    return expectedText.isEmpty ? input : expectedText
}
```

Comment: Better to start with `expectedText` as being `""` (non-optional), then you can just use `expectedText += value`

Comment: @Alexander could do, but then the return becomes `return expectedText == "" ? input : expectedText`. But you're right, having a single ternary operator is better than using the default value in each iteration of nested loops

Comment: @DávidPásztor Even better, use `expectedText.isEmpty`, but yeah, I would say that's far better. Nitpick: that's the *conditional operator*. It is a ternary operator (in that it's an operator that takes 3 operands), and it happens to currently be the only ternary operator in Swift, but nothing says there might never be another.

Comment: @Alexander I always forget the proper name of the _conditional operator_, thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you might do it using `compactMap` with a `[Character : Character]` dictionary:

```
let letterDict: [Character : Character] = ["a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3", "d": "4"]

let str = "ab"
var newstr = String(str.compactMap { letterDict[$0] })
print(newstr) // 12
```

This will return the empty string `""` if no characters matched, whereas your code returned the original string.  If that is the desired result, you could follow this with:

```
newstr = newstr.isEmpty ? str : newstr
```

---

So your function becomes:

```
func convertText(_ input: String) -> String {
    let expectedText = String(input.compactMap { letterDict[$0] })
    return expectedText.isEmpty ? input : expectedText
}

print(convertText("ab")) // 12
print(convertText("ef")) // ef
```

Comment: And even if the dict has to be `[Character: String]`, it's trivial to just `str.compactMap { letterDict[$0] }.joined(separator: "")`

Comment: That's true @Alexander, although `.joined()` is sufficient.

Comment: Oh interesting, I didn't know the `separator` had a defaulted value :o